# Ionic @awesome-cordova-plugins/chooser not returning file path

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am running an Ionic 6 application on Android. I am building it with capacitor. The dependencies relevant to this are "@awesome-cordova-plugins/chooser": "^6.3.0" and "cordova-plugin-chooser": "^1.3.2". I have the following in my ImageHandlerService:

```
import { Chooser } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/chooser/ngx';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ImageHandlerService {
  nativepath: any;
  firestore = firebase.storage();
  constructor(private chooser: Chooser,
              private calcService: CalculationService,
              public platform: Platform) {

  }

uploadAndHandleURLChange(oldURL: string): Promise<ExitMessage> {
  const rand = this.calcService.makeRandomIdFromDate();
  const up = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid +  '-' + rand;
  const bucketPath = '/profileimages/' + up;

  if (this.platform.is("android")) {
    return this.chooser.getFile().then((file) => {
        console.log("uploadAndHandleURLChange file %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%", file);
        console.log("uploadAndHandleURLChange file.name  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%", file.name);
        console.log("uploadAndHandleURLChange file.path %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%", file.path);
        console.log("uploadAndHandleURLChange file.extension %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%", file.extension);
        console.log("uploadAndHandleURLChange file.mimeType %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%", file.mimeType);
        console.log("uploadAndHandleURLChange file.displayName %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%", file.displayName);

        const filesPath  = file.path;
    
        const fileType   = file.mimeType;
        
        return this.profileToNativePathAndStore(filesPath, fileType, oldURL, bucketPath);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("uploadAndHandleURLChange err %%%%%%%%%%%%5", err);
        const exit: ExitMessage = {
          exit: 1,
          success: false
        }

        return exit;
      });
   }
  }
}
```

As you can see I am debugging with all of the possible values from file. However, when running this on both my android phone and android emulator, after I choose a file, I get the following output:

```
File: http://localhost/405.js - Line 1 - Msg: uploadAndHandleURLChange file %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% [object Object]

File: http://localhost/405.js - Line 1 - Msg: uploadAndHandleURLChange file.name  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% photo-abcd.jpeg

File: http://localhost/405.js - Line 1 - Msg: uploadAndHandleURLChange file.path %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% undefined

File: http://localhost/405.js - Line 1 - Msg: uploadAndHandleURLChange file.extension %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% undefined

File: http://localhost/405.js - Line 1 - Msg: uploadAndHandleURLChange file.mimeType %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% undefined

File: http://localhost/405.js - Line 1 - Msg: uploadAndHandleURLChange file.displayName %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% undefined
```

Where the only value returned is the file name. However, in order to upload this, I need the file path and file type as well. I cannot figure out why those values are being returned to me as undefined. Any help is appreciated.